# Learning to use a modular approach. Have to save multiple files to see result of css?

Tags: import, sass, save, repeat, modularity

Ok, I am trying to learn to use a modular approach to my css for scalable and modular development. My file structure is similar to this.

[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXmZ3.png)

Now, I have a red border on every element that I toggle on and off it helps me visualize as I position elements. Its the first line of code in my _grid.sass file. I have a single file named main.sass with only

```
@import '_base.sass' 
@import '_grid.sass' 
@import '_colors.sass'
```

inside of it. Then, I use atom editor's auto compile to convert main.sass into main.min.css which is linked to the html file. So if I turn off the border property in _grid.sass. I have to save that file, then save main.sass, then save _grid.sass again. I have to be doing something wrong, because if I want to develop an entire site like this, I will have to save 3 times for each individual change, and that will add up to about 5 million redundant saves a minute. Can someone give me some information on this?

Comment: This is confusing me because the html file is set to live preview with the main.min.css file. Which is compiled from main.sass (Full of @imports) which is what I am making changes too. So, if I change _grids.sass, in a way, I am also changing main.min.css right? Since main.sass is just a bridge between main.min.css and _grids.sass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using the [sass-autocompile](https://atom.io/packages/sass-autocompile) package. While this is great for single file projects, it doesn't work so well for larger projects.

Instead I would advise using a build system like [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) or [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/). I am more familiar with gulp, so here is a modified version of my build system to work with your project structure.

In order to use this you will need to install [gulp](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) and the other packages imported.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    return gulp.src('stylesheets/main.scss')
        .pipe(
            sass({
                outputStyle: 'compressed',
                includePaths: ['stylesheets/modules', 'stylesheets/partials', 'stylesheets/vendor']
            }).on('error', sass.logError)
        )
        .pipe(rename('compiled.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('stylesheets'));
});
```

Also, you don't need to (and shouldn't) include the underscore and extension in your partial names, so use `@import 'base';` instead of `@import '_base.scss';`

Comment: I edited it to watch for changes of any sass file. It works perfectly   https://jsbin.com/xekoderevi/edit?js,output